# Where to put httpcomponents-client-android 4.3.5 in android studio

Tags: android

I know this will be a dumb question, but i downloaded httpcomponents-client-android 4.3.5 (android) to the apache website and im clueless where should i put this file in my android studio project. i tried the .jar files of other versions but some class' arent there so i would like to try this file but im clueless to where should i paste this in my file. guys where should i paste this file that i downloaded in my android studio? and  btw, im using android studio than eclipse. im kinda new in this stuff.

Comment: Dude take a look at how to inculde a dependency using gradle if you are using android studio that will save a lot of time (no downloading and no manual including... everything is automated).

Comment: Paste the JAR files into `libs` folder. Note that it perhaps does not works for API23 projects